# In Android Studio, building one project of a multi-project setup with Gradle, can I make it only build one of the projects?

Tags: android, performance, build, gradle, android-studio

I have a multi-project setup in Gradle and work in Android-studio. The setup contains two apps (each one has its own project directory with its own build.gradle) and some libraries shared by those apps.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
/workspace/
/workspace/app1/
/workspace/app2/
/workspace/app3/
/workspace/library1/
/workspace/library1/
```

When I build from the command line I can limit the build to only one of the apps via

```
gradle assembleDebugApp1
```

When I build from within Android Studio, it seems to build *all* projects that have a build.gradle file and are inside of workspace.

In Android Studio, when I run `Build->Make Project`, I see on the bottom what gradle does:

`Gradle build using tasks: [:app1:assembleDebug, :app2:assembleDebug, library1:bundleDebug, (...)]`.

I would like it to only run the assemble task for my "current project".

I'm new to AndroidStudio, so maybe the question is : How do I set the "current project'? 
How do I tell Android Studio to only build what I need for `app1`?

---

Edit based on replies:

I *do* want to run gradle via make so it does give feedback back to the IDE, because I'd like to see the "Make Messages" window:

[image: Make messages window screengrab]

Answer (score 1):

Open Gradle tasks tab and select task to run. You can select a task from subprojects.

[image: Selecting Gradle task]

On command line:

```
gradle :app1:assembleDebug
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed works. But this is still basically running the command line gradle within the Android Studio IDE. Definitely nice to know and I will surely use this, however, what I really want is to run `Build-> Make Project` : I do need the messages window where I can jump to my errors etc. (see picture in edited post).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an "official" way of handling this yet but I got around it by creating a new "Run Configuration" and replacing the default "Build" option in the "Before Launch" section with my own command that calls Gradle with the relevant command line options.

[image]

Comment: This indeed works. What I really want is to run Build-> Make Project : I do need the messages window where I can jump to my errors etc. (see picture in edited post).